# How to test that JSON-only controller returns 406

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a controller that should only accept application/json or */*. I check this in the controller class:

```
...
include ActionController::MimeResponds

before_action :require_json

def require_json
  respond_to :json
end
....
```

That works pretty well, although there is an UnknownFormat error in the log every time a client uses an invalid accept header. The controller correctly returns HTTP 406 Not acceptable.

In the test I write:

```
...
test 'do not accept plain text' do
  assert_raises ActionController::UnknownFormat do
    get '/api/v1/ping', headers: {'Accept' => 'text/plain'}
  end
  assert_response :not_acceptable
...
```

Then Rake aborts with undefined method error at accept_response since the response is nil. I assume it is not set the normal execution flow aborts at the unknown format exception. But if I do not assert the exception the test will just abort with it.

Is it a good idea to throw an exception at every 406? How can I test that I get a 406 returned?

Comment: it's just my opinion, but I wouldn't raise an exception in this case. I'd  be sure to propagate it back to the client of the JSON interface and allow them to react to it in accordance to their design and business logic.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/ResponseAssertions.html

You need to

```
assert_response 406
```

Comment: That yields the same error. I think the code is not the problem, but the response object is nil when doing the get inside an assert_raises. But if I don't catch the exception the test will abort.

Comment: You might be right. If your response is nil you are doing something out of order. Sorry i couldnt help more but I will check it out again